# What is the current status of Spyro the Dragon?

Tags: skylanders, spyro-series

My favorite games for the Playstation were the original three "Spyro the Dragon" games. I was attempting to catch up with the franchise, but have been unable to determine the current state of Spyro continuity - apparently the franchise was [rebooted in 2006](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Spyro), and Spyro is also part of the Skylander games.

I'm under the impression that there may be more recent games featuring Spyro but I'm unclear on where the multiple games stand in understanding Spyro's world apart from the separate Skylanders continuity.

What games are considered part of the current Spyro timeline/continuity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most recent game featuring Spyro outside of Skylanders is *The Legend of Spyro: Dawn of the Dragon*, released in 2008.

This is part of the trilogy *[The Legend of Spyro](http://spyro.wikia.com/wiki/The_Legend_of_Spyro_(series))* - a reboot of the series which is comprised of these three games:

- [The Legend of Spyro: A New Beginning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Spyro:_A_New_Beginning)
- [The Legend of Spyro: The Eternal Night](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Spyro:_The_Eternal_Night)
- [The Legend of Spyro: Dawn of the Dragon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Spyro:_Dawn_of_the_Dragon)

Comment: Thank you - I was under the impression that there were more recent games, but this answers my question exactly.

Comment: As far as I have heard Spyro as a character is kind of in limbo and it just used as platform to release Skylanders off of.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, the original trilogy has been "reignited" into [*Spyro Reignited Trilogy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spyro_Reignited_Trilogy), a remake of the original trilogy with enhanced graphics and audio and playable on both PS4 and Xbox One.

The game was released with missing levels from both *Ripto's Rage!* and *Year of the Dragon*, but those were added in the 1.01 patch.